# Service Failed 1053 Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am getting the following error if I run `Neo4j.bat console`:

```
20 May 2013 1:05:08 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
WARNING: WARNING! You are using an unsupported version of the Java runtime. Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) Runtime Environment 7.
20 May 2013 1:05:11 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
INFO: Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
20 May 2013 1:05:16 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@1a19458' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:314)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:205)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:286)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:129)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@1a19458' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:292)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@6b496d' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:128)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.InvalidRecordException: NodeRecord[327] not in use
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NodeStore.getRecord(NodeStore.java:239)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NodeStore.getRecord(NodeStore.java:112)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.gatherUpdatesFromPropertyCommands(WriteTransaction.java:692)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.convertIntoLogicalPropertyUpdates(WriteTransaction.java:669)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.applyCommit(WriteTransaction.java:619)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.WriteTransaction.doCommit(WriteTransaction.java:561)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.commit(XaTransaction.java:321)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.injectTwoPhaseCommit(XaResourceManager.java:407)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.applyTwoPhaseCommitEntry(XaLogicalLog.java:562)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.applyEntry(XaLogicalLog.java:437)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.doInternalRecovery(XaLogicalLog.java:771)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:206)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:161)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaContainer.openLogicalLog(XaContainer.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:310)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 15 more
20 May 2013 1:05:16 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

I have uninstalled all old versions of the JRE and installed Oracle Jave Runtime Enviroment 7 aswell as restarted my computer and I still get the same error? How do I fix this error?

Comment: I don't see 1053 in your output. Did you mean 10053 with an extra zero? That's Windows's "could not connect" socket error. I'd guess from the final cause `NodeRecord[327] not in use` that some data store Neo4j is trying to use is corrupted, though. Can you reinitialise that somehow? And are you definitely running Java 7? Does `java -version` show you 1.7? Try setting a JAVA_HOME environment to the root of your 1.7 JDK and putting the JDK bin directory in your path ahead of any other Java.

Comment: If i do the `java -version` it says `1.7.0`. I have also set the JAVA_HOME enviroment variable to the directory of Java 7. How do I put the JDK bin directory in my path ahead of other java versions?

Comment: Ok it worked! post an answer @Rup

Comment: Done, thanks! Glad it worked - I was expecting it to be complicated than that!

Comment: This rather seems like a store issue, would it be possible for you to share your graph.db directory zipped somewhere? If so, please send a link to michael at neo4j dot org and refer this SO issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's still picking up the wrong version of Java, you should check your environment variables (Control Panel, System, Advanced, Environment)

- set `JAVA_HOME` to be the root of your JDK home directory, e.g. `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21`
- make sure that the `jdk1.7.0_xx\bin` directory appears in your `PATH` ahead of any other Java installations you have; note that this might have to be ahead of `C:\Windows\System32` since Microsoft's java selector code is in there

If you're running Neo4J as a service it's easiest to add these to the "System Variables" section but you could also set it up for the user that the service is running as.